# How to type hint function that accepts Union of TypedDicts and Union of Literals?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

So i have a situation like this example:

```
from typing import Literal, overload, TypedDict, LiteralString

class Test1(TypedDict)
    test1: str

class Test2(TypedDict):
    test2: str

@overload
def _get_actor_key(
    actor: Literal["test1"],
    game_action: Test1,
) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def _get_actor_key(
    actor: Literal["test2"], game_action: Test2
) -> str:
    ...


def _get_actor_key(
    actor: Literal["test1","test2"],
    game_action: Test1 | Test2,
) -> str:
    return game_action[actor]
```

Where i have a set of TypedDicts and want to extract some information from them. For each TypedDict there is a limited set of Literals that is allowed to be passed into the function with some overlap between the dicts.

Is there any way to type hint this without writing a separate function for each TypedDict?

With the more direct use case

```
@overload
def _get_actor_key(
    actor: Literal["attacker", "victim", "assister", "flashThrower", "playerTraded"],
    game_action: KillAction,
) -> str:
    ...


@overload
def _get_actor_key(
    actor: Literal["attacker", "player"], game_action: FlashAction
) -> str:
    ...


def _get_actor_key(
    actor: GameActionPlayers,
    game_action: GameAction,
) -> str:  # type: ignore[reportGeneralTypeIssues]
    return (
        str(game_action[actor + "Name"])  # type: ignore[reportGeneralTypeIssues]
        if game_action[actor + "SteamID"] == 0  # type: ignore[reportGeneralTypeIssues]
        else str(game_action[actor + "SteamID"])  # type: ignore[reportGeneralTypeIssues]
    )
```

Where for some of the game actions i can ask for killer,victim,... name and steamid where as others only support playername and playersteamid.

Comment: The situation you describe is *exactly* overloads use case, and they cannot be generated dynamically. If you need an extremely large amount of overloads (over 20), you may want to go with code generation way (e.g. a Jinja2 template which renders to python code or stubs).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid such an overloaded function entirely.
`_get_actor_key` itself seems like the `get` method of an appropriate `TypedDict`, mapping strings to actor-specific functions.

```
from typing import TypedDict


class Test1(TypedDict):
    test1: str


class Test2(TypedDict):
    test2: str


class ActorKeys(TypedDict):
    test1: Callable[[Test1], str]
    test2: Callable[[Test2], str]


def test1_actor(game_action: Test1) -> str:
    return ""


def test2_actor(game_action: Test2) -> str:
    return ""


d: ActorKeys = {'test1': test1_actor, 'test2': test2_actor}
f: Callable[[Test1], str] = d['test1']
```

Comment: I updated my example a bit but im not sure if that changes anything for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [PEP692](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/) is the only relevant one here. It specifically [rejects unions of typed dicts](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/#typeddict-unions) idea because it doesn't want to deal with the complexity. Nothing else has superseded it thus far.

That said, there's a decent workaround which would let you get close to what you're looking for here through the use of a third `TypedDict`. Note that the code below is in python 3.10 so some of the `typing_extensions` imports may be moved to the import from the `typing` module.

```
from typing import Literal, overload, TypedDict
from typing_extensions import Unpack, NotRequired

class T1(TypedDict):
  t1: int

class T2(TypedDict):
  t2: int

# TypedDict must be the last class here or you can't get a
# consistent import order.
class T3(TypedDict):
  t1: NotRequired[int]
  t2: NotRequired[int]

@overload
def foo(a: Literal['t1'], **b: Unpack[T1]):
  ...

@overload
def foo(a: Literal['t2'], **b: Unpack[T2]):
  ...

def foo(a: Literal['t1', 't2'], **b: Unpack[T3]):
  ...
```

So yea, your options are either to write separate functions or manually write the extra `TypedDict`. I think most people would suggest just using the first option, but I personally pick the second option. It really depends on your use case though.

Comment: What i have now gone with is just type hinting the actual implementation as Any. This means i dont get any type checking as i would want it IN the function but i do get it when calling the function as there it ignores the type hints on the implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, Python's typing module doesn't support the kind of `keyof` operations which Typescript does. Despite that, I've honestly been both pleasantly surprised by the expressiveness of Python's typing and simultaneously disappointed in the ergonomics of it.